# Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

This is probably a shot in the dark since it is so early in the release of Visual Studio, but I am looking for more information on Visual Studio 2015 and the versions that are coming out, are there any resources out there that show what is coming.

I am asking because we are trying to plan what versions of Visual Studio to purchase in the future and we are already developing using CTP 5.

So with that being said, is Visual Studio going to be structured the same way with Ultimate, Premium, Professional, Community, etc?

Comment: Sorry, no offense intended. It's not an answer, just a comment, feel free to ignore it. But it says exactly what you wouldn't want to hear: even though someone would say to you that versions set is defined, there is no any slightest guarantee that it won't be changed at any moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was what I was waiting for:

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs-2015-product-editions

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be any official word on the [release date](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a6d430cc-8675-4382-a5aa-8fcf15bde492/visual-studio-2015-release-date?forum=vssetup) or pricing structure for VS 2015. The default assumption would be they will maintain the current structure as VS 2013. The current pre-release of 2015 is referred to as "Ultimate" on the [download page](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx) (although there aren't any other tiers present).

Since 2013 was originally released they have introduced the free Community Version (roughly same as Professional) and made .NET open sourced, which may indicate upcoming changes.

I wouldn't expect any drastic changes to the distribution model though without advance announcement, simply because the kind of customers that buy the high-end versions of VS (like yourself) need stability in their tools. There's no way to say for sure though right now.

Comment: Thanks Greg, "Since 2013 was originally released they have introduced the free Community Version (roughly same as Professional) and made .NET open sourced, which may indicate upcoming changes." is exactly why I am asking.  I know the Microsoft team regularly monitors the boards here so I was just hoping to get their insights.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently running VS 2015 Enterprise with Windows 10 on Hyper-V.  I wanted to install on Virtual Machine since VS2015 is still beta.  With an MSDN subscription you should be able to download the Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise RC as an .iso file.